# Cannot assign value to static integer

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, static

I am working on a project with threads. This is the beginning of my main class.

```
public class Main {
    public static int firstIndex, secondIndex, thirdIndex, fourthIndex, fifthIndex;
```

Then I create a thread and override its run() function. Inside the run() I try to assign integers to my static integer variables that I defined earlier.

```
cThread thread1 = new cThread(ant) {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    firstIndex = myAllocator.alloc(11, '1', this);
                    secondIndex = myAllocator.alloc(10, '2', this);
```

The alloc() function returns the correct integers inside, but the static variables always remain at 0 and do not change to the values that the function returns. However, if I do not make the integers static, it gives the following error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field firstIndex.
```

I am sure the functions return correct values. What is the problem? Many thanks.

Comment: Try Main.firstIndex.

Comment: It didn't work, there is no syntax error but it still stays at 0. It also won't let me change from static to normal integer.

Comment: Please, **please**, **PLEASE** read _some_ documentation on how threading works in Java. You have no synchronization and no `volatile`. It is absolutely no surprise that your code doesn't work.

Comment: @YaseenKhan But of course you can.

Comment: Is the run() method that you showed us somewhere _inside_ the `Main` class?  Or is it in some other class?  Is there some other variable named `firstIndex` anywhere in the program?  It would be much easier for other people to help you if you could show us a _small_, _complete_ program that other people can compile and run.  Chances are though, that you will find the answer on your own if you try to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following things:

- That you are running the thread. `thread1.start()`
- That you are checking the static variables after the thread has completed. After all the purpose of threads is to run in parallel so you might be checking for the values before the thread has had a chance to run.
- You need synchronization. Either make the static variables `volatile` or wrap your login inside the `run` method of the thread with a `synchronized` block. You will need to use a synchronized block when reading as well. It is possible that the values are being correctly set by one Core but a different Core is trying to read them. Without synchronization, you have no guarantee that both Cores will see the proper data. (due to caching and such)

Comment: Yes, it is fixed now. Apparently I was trying to use the integers that I would acquire before the thread was completed, so it never got to assign. :[

Comment: `volatile` is an extremely weak form of synchronization.  If you want one thread to update a variable, and another thread to read the updated value; `volatile` will guarantee that the value is propagated from the one thread to the other, but _only if_ the read actually happens after the write.  Using `volatile` does nothing to ensure that the read won't happen _before_ the write.  You need `wait()` and `notify()`, or you need some higher level construct built on wait/notify-like primitives to ensure that the read and write happen in the right order.

Comment: @james large - `volatile` is just a mechanism for synchronization like `synchronized`. It guarantees nothing about the order of reading / writing. This is left to the developer depending on their desired logic. They might have multiple reads / writes and might not need to wait on anything and this could be valid for their use case. Still, `volatile` assures that you will get a valid old or new value and nothing in between.

Comment: I would always opt for synchronized blocks, though as their are more explicit about where reading and writing is performed. If one were to want a more complicated behaviour, they should definitely check the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are assigning values from a new thread, you should wait for the thread to complete before reading the values.
2. Expecting writes to be seen by reads on different threads requires thread synchronization. Define the variables as volatile, or protect them with a lock.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the variables static; 
So you'd change your first line of code by

```
public int firstIndex, secondIndex,...
```